# return type for findAndModify with futures

Tags: scala, future, reactive-programming

Say I'm using an async library to read and write data. If a failure, I get an error message as a string, otherwise the data. Is there a better way to represent the return type than `Future[Either[String, Future[Data]]]`?

Possible implementation:

```
  def createData(name: String): Future[Either[String, Future[Data]]] = {
    dataDAO.findOneByName(name).flatMap {
      case Some(data) =>
        Future.successful(Left(s"Data with name already exists. $name"))
      case None =>
        val data = Data.createFromName(name)
        dataDAO.save(data).map {
          lastError =>
            data
        }.right.futureSuccessful
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why use `Future[Either[String, Future[Data]]]` instead of `Future[Either[String, Data]]`?

Comment: Why not wrap the error message in an exception and use `Future.failed`?

Comment: @izstas i think using a exception here would be bad. You shouldn't use exceptions for "business-errors", and a record already exists is a totally expecting scenario, so it's no "exception". Using a either as return type makes the signature much more clear and verbose for the consumer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return type should be `Future[Either[String, Data]]`

To archive this you need to change your second case to:

```
case None =>
    val data = Data.createFromName(name)
    dataDAO.save(data).map {
      _ => Right(data)
    }
```

I even would improve your error type from `String` to e.g. `CreateDataError`, so your return type would be `Future[Either[CreateDataError, Data]]` and your first case would be

```
// Having somewhere decalred
trait CreateDataError
object DataAlreadyExistsError

//...
//...

case Some(data) =>
    Future.successful(Left(DataAlreadyExistsError))
```

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I overlooked this future/either combination.